# strange error during cast to __m128i

Tags: c, sse, sse2

I'm trying to cast unsigned short array to `__m128i`:

```
const unsigned short x[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15};
const unsigned short y[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15};

__m128i n = *(__m128i*) &y[0];
__m128i m = *(__m128i*) &x[0];
```

First casting work fine, but the second one - not. I've got:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x013839ee in sse2_test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xffffffff.
```

What's wrong? Can somebody help me?

Comment: BTW, did you even realize that 16 `shorts` don't fit into a `__m128i`?

Answer (score 12):

Watch your data alignment.

When you dereference a `__m128i*` or any other SSE type, the pointer is required to be aligned to 16 bytes. However, `x` and `y` are not guaranteed to be aligned to 16 bytes.

Enforcing alignment is dependent on the compiler.

**Visual C++**

```
__declspec(align(16)) const unsigned short x[] = ...
```

**GCC**

```
const unsigned short x[] __attribute__((aligned(16))) = ...
```

---

Alternatively, you can use unaligned loads (abeit at a possible performance penalty):

```
__m128i n = __mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*) &y[0]);
__m128i m = __mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*) &x[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't blindly cast one pointer type to another one, as Mystical says you should expect alignment problems, then. C11 has `_Alignas` and other compilers have extension to C99 or C89 to do the same thing.

The official, and as I find clearest, method to such a thing with C99 is to create a `union`:

```
union combine {
  unsigned short x[sizeof(__m128i)/sizeof(unsigned short)];
  __m128i y;
}

union combine X = { .x = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15} };
```

Such a `union` is guaranteed to be correctly aligned for all its members.
Now you easily can use `X.y` and you don't even have to go through pointer references.

Comment: This is the canonical way recommended by the gcc folks. Unfortunately it tends to produce inferior code (to much register spilling). BTW, `unsigned short x[sizeof(__m128i)]` doesn't make any sense. Either `sizeof(__m128i)/sizeof(short)` to get the numbers of shorts fitting into a `__m128i` or simply `16` to match the number of elements given.

Comment: @drhirsch, thanks for spotting the error, corrected. Though I have some serious doubts that this should be `16`. This is `16` bytes isn't it and not `16` `short`, no? And so the initializer (also in the question) would be just wrong, wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, thats what I meant. See my comment at the question.